# Select Id from column = 1 and column 2 MsSql 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

```
SELECT Distinct ListingId,FieldId,FieldValue
  FROM [Chant-GreyPar].[dbo].[gp_listing_field]
  where (FieldId = 54) and (FieldId = 69)
      order by ListingId asc
```

Hello Guys I have table

```
ListingId   FieldId FieldValue
238878  54  Paupackan Lake
238878  69  N
238879  54  None
238879  69  N
238880  54  Westcolang Lake
238881  54  None
238882  54  None
```

I need to select id that got FieldId 54 and 69 ... Need ur help.

UPDATE:

```
select distinct l.Id,[SquareFeet],[HouseNumber],[StreetAddress],[PropertyTypeId],[Bedrooms],[Bathrooms],[ListingPrice],
(select top 1 PhotoUrl from [Chant-GreyPar].dbo.gp_listing_photo where gp_listing_photo.ListingId = f.ListingId ) AS PhotoUrl,  
(Select AreaName1 from [Chant-GreyPar].dbo.gp_location where gp_location.Id = l.LocationId) AS AreaName1,
(Select AreaStateCode from [Chant-GreyPar].dbo.gp_location where gp_location.Id = l.LocationId) AS AreaStateCode 
from [Chant-GreyPar].dbo.gp_listing l inner join [Chant-GreyPar].[dbo].[gp_listing_field] f 
on f.ListingId = l.Id left join [Chant-GreyPar].dbo.gp_vw_DecimalListingField s on s.ListingId = l.Id 
where  (l.DisplayListing='1' and  f.FieldId='69' and f.FieldValue='Y') and (l.DisplayListing='1' and f.FieldId='15' and f.FieldValue='Window Unit AC' or f.FieldValue='Wall Unit AC' or f.FieldValue='Window Unit AC' or f.FieldValue='Central AC')
 and ListingPrice >= 0 and ListingPrice <= 99999999999 and Bedrooms >= 0 and Bathrooms >= 0 
 and SquareFeet >= 0  and (FieldValueDecimal >= 0 or FieldValueDecimal is null ) 
 order by ListingPrice desc
```

How to integrate here it. Thnks.

Comment: It's not possible for a FieldId to ever be both 59 _and_ 64. You should use OR instead (or use an IN() condition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ListingId, FieldId, FieldValue
FROM [Chant-GreyPar].[dbo].[gp_listing_field]
WHERE ListingId IN (
    SELECT ListingId
    FROM [Chant-GreyPar].[dbo].[gp_listing_field]
    WHERE FieldId IN ( 54, 69 )
    GROUP BY ListingId
    HAVING Count(ListingId) = 2
)
ORDER BY ListingId ASC
```

This uses a sub-query (the SELECT statement inside the WHERE clause), to get a list of all ListingId that have 2 records.  The WHERE clause in the sub-query filters by the 2 values you're looking for - 54 and 69 - so it will only give you the records that have both a 54 and 69.  The main query then uses that list to get the values for just those rows.

Your update is a little complicated without having the database in front of me.  All you should have to do is use my sub-query in place of the first part of your WHERE clause where you're searching for FieldId values.  No guarantee my syntax is correct here:

```
USE [Chant-GreyPar]  -- This eliminates the need to keep repeating it in the query
GO
SELECT DISTINCT l.Id, SquareFeet, HouseNumber, StreetAddress, PropertyTypeId, Bedrooms, Bathrooms, ListingPrice,
    (SELECT TOP 1 PhotoUrl FROM dbo.gp_listing_photo WHERE gp_listing_photo.ListingId = f.ListingId ) AS PhotoUrl,  
    (SELECT AreaName1 FROM dbo.gp_location WHERE gp_location.Id = l.LocationId) AS AreaName1,
    (SELECT AreaStateCode FROM dbo.gp_location WHERE gp_location.Id = l.LocationId) AS AreaStateCode 
FROM dbo.gp_listing l
INNER JOIN dbo.gp_listing_field f ON f.ListingId = l.Id
LEFT JOIN dbo.gp_vw_DecimalListingField s ON s.ListingId = l.Id 
WHERE ListingId IN (
    SELECT ListingId
    FROM dbo.gp_listing_field
    WHERE (l.DisplayListing='1' AND f.FieldId='69' AND f.FieldValue='Y')
    OR (l.DisplayListing='1' AND f.FieldId='15' AND f.FieldValue IN ('Window Unit AC', 'Wall Unit AC', 'Window Unit AC', 'Central AC' ))
    GROUP BY ListingId
    HAVING Count(ListingId) = 2
)
AND ListingPrice BETWEEN 0 AND 99999999999
AND Bedrooms >= 0
AND Bathrooms >= 0
AND SquareFeet >= 0
AND (FieldValueDecimal >= 0 OR FieldValueDecimal IS NULL)
ORDER BY ListingPrice DESC
```

By the way, you changed the second FieldId value from 54 to 15.  Not sure if that was intentional.

Comment: Are you saying you need to get the ListingId only where it links to both a 54 and 69 record?

Comment: I think it work for me , can u explain how it works.

Comment: Look , I update ur answer , now I have example harder. If u help me , I will bring u flowers :D

Comment: Don`t return records , that i want.

Comment: I don`t understand why I don`t get result what I want.

Comment: It something else, can u create some test table to test it. Because i get 0 results.

Comment: 'select k.Id from [Chant-GreyPar].dbo.gp_listing k inner join (
 select l.Id from [Chant-GreyPar].dbo.gp_listing l inner join [Chant-GreyPar].dbo.gp_listing_field f on l.Id = f.ListingId
 where l.DisplayListing='1' AND f.FieldId='68' AND f.FieldValue='Y'
) 
 inner join (
  select l.Id from [Chant-GreyPar].dbo.gp_listing l
 inner join [Chant-GreyPar].dbo.gp_listing_field f on l.Id = f.ListingId
 where l.DisplayListing='1' and f.FieldId='15' and f.FieldValue='Window Unit AC' or f.FieldValue='Wall Unit AC' or f.FieldValue='Window Unit AC' or f.FieldValue='Central AC'

Comment: This query return just one result. And it`s wright. Ur query retun 0 result(

Comment: You will need to update your question with your tables and some sample data.  There's no way to check the results without that.

Comment: I think , I will work with joins. It just one method that solved my problem.